# Show that, $\displaystyle (m+n)I_{m,n}~=~\sin \dfrac{n\pi}{2}-mJ_{m-1,n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Given,
$$\displaystyle I_{m,n}~=~\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos (nx) (\sin x)^{m}~ \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\displaystyle J_{m,n}~=~\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin (nx) (\sin x)^m ~\mathrm{d}x$$
Show that,
$$\displaystyle (m+n)I_{m,n}~=~\sin \dfrac{n\pi}{2}-mJ_{m-1,n-1}$$

I have been trying this problem for a long time. First I tried to apply by parts but failed.
I need some help to start off. A rigorous and wordy proof is needed.

Comment: try to include your working for integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$I_{m,n} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(nx) (\sin x)^mdx$$

$$\implies I_{m,n} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2} - nx\right) (\cos x)^mdx$$

I used the property that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: After this just apply by parts?

Comment: I guess, I didn't solve it fully.. but it looks like solving by parts will get you from I to J

Comment: This is fine but Dhanvi is there any elegant proof